# Is there a way to detect Android's dark/night mode?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to detect Android's dark/night mode? Additionally, is there a way to inherit dark styles?

I see a build hint [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) android.theme that can be light or dark. Its description also says it might be dark in the future but no further explanation is given

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. These are both things that we need to provide a better solution for on iOS and desktop too. I suggest [filing an RFE](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new) for this.

That build hint is part of a legacy from the Android 2.x days and shouldn't be applicable.